# Opening the same file twice with different flags?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Can I open the same file twice (with [CreateFileA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx)), using different flags (in this case, one with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, and one without)?

In detail, this is the case: During startup, I create a temporary file (with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE). I fill it up sequentially, and I don't want to worry about doing unbuffered IO in this part. Then, while the process is running, I want to access that file using unbuffered IO, because I have my own caching logic. Thus, I'm thinking of opening the same file again, this time with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, and then closing the old handle. I want to do this in this overlapped way for two reasons:

1. Concurrency. If I close the old handle before I open the new one, someone else might mess with my file in the meantime.
2. FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE would delete my file when I close the first handle without having another one open. This is a minor annoyance that I could work around.

Comment: Random question: Why the heck would you want to use `CreateFileA` instead of `CreateFileW`?

Comment: I didn't write the whole system myself, only this part. They give me the filename as a char*, so I use it as a char* :-) Besides, I could write a whole rant about why WCHAR is stupid, except, of course, that its use is so abundant in the Windows APIs that you kind of have to use it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry for my sentiment here but I get bitten often enough by applications that refuse to open files just because I have a few folders that use Unicode that doesn't fit in the legacy codepage.

Comment: I don't do winapi stuff much but if there a good reason to use `CreateFile` instead of `fopen` or `fstream`?

Comment: Yes, @Kitsune. The techniques you mention don't allow specifying stuff such as the buffering mode or the deletion mode, which is the topic of this question.

Comment: @Rob well `setvbuf` allows for full, line, and no buffering. If you want a file that will be deleted on close, try using `tmpfile` or `fopen` and `tmpnam`. To reopen with different access, try `freopen` and to change the buffer mode/size use `setvbuf` and `setbuf`. For a full list of functions that operate with FILE* see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember to include FILE_SHARE_DELETE in share mode. I think FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE is the only flag that affects more than just "your" handle.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it ridiculous?

You want to open twice because if open after close previous handle someone might mess with your file. But reality is that you are trying to mess with your file.

If can not guarantee exclusive file access how can you prevent someone doing something? But if you open exclusively how you can reopen the file?

AFAIK, if the file is already opened exclusively no more open is allowed, even from the same process.

Comment: While it is true that he would need to specify shared write when opening the file for the first time, he could then lock it with LockFile(), but since he is using FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE I assume this is a temporary file and no other app is going to mess with it probably

Comment: @Anders LockFile.. oh.. I didn't knew such API exist. Thank you for enlightening comment.